# How to build program using custom header files, both using SFML library?

Tags: c++, linker-errors, sfml, header-files

So, I was trying to create a custom header file, which will contain my implementation of several graphics functions like drawPixel,drawLine, etc.Both my source file(with main function), and header file includes SFML library. When I use sfml functions in my source file, it runs without error, but when I use the same functions in header file, it shows "linker command failed".

**sfml.cpp(source file)**

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "my_graphics.h"
int main()
{

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "SFML works!");

while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            window.close();
        }
    }


    // Clear the window
    window.clear();
    
    putPixel(window,100,100);
    window.display();

}
return 0;
```

}

**my_graohics.h**

```
#ifndef MY_GRAPHICS_H
#define MY_GRAPHICS_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

void putPixel(sf::RenderTarget& target, int x, int y);

#endif
```

**my_graphics.cpp**

```
#include "my_graphics.h"
void putPixel(sf::RenderTarget& target, int x, int y) {
sf::Vertex vertex;
vertex.position = sf::Vector2f(x, y);
vertex.color = sf::Color::White;

sf::VertexArray point(sf::Points, 1);
point[0] = vertex;

target.draw(point);
}
```

**build command**

```
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -std=c++17 -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g sfml.cpp 
-o sfml -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.0/include -L 
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.0/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, always copy-paste the full and complete build-log into the question itself.

Comment: Though it's easy to ***guess*** the problem here, because you don't build with your `my_graphics.cpp` source file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the hint man, previously I was trying to compile both the files separately and then link libraries to them, it was not working, when I compiled them together with libraries, it built successfully. 
Thanks!!

Comment: If you want to build separately (which you really need to do for larger projects) then use the `-c` option to create object files, and then link those object files with the libraries to create the executable program. I suggest you either start using an IDE, or learn about build-tools such as `make` or high-level tools like CMake. It will help you with handling of larger projects with multiple source files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of compiling the files separately "sfml.cpp" and "my_graphics.cpp" with libraries linked to each of them.
I compiled them together, and linked the libraries.

Command:

```
clang++ -std=gnu++14 -std=c++17 -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g sfml.cpp my_graphics.cpp -o program -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.0/include -L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.0/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
```

Comment: What's the reason behind using both `-std=gnu++14` and `-std=c++17` in the same build command? I don't think it makes any sense.